# How to run gulp tasks before publishing to Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, task-runner-explorer

I have some gulp tasks which I run with Task Runner Explorer. I would like to run those tasks along with building my server-side code (which Visual Studio does automatically before attempting to publish) before publishing to Azure. I don't see how to tell the publish process about my gulp tasks or my gulp tasks about the publication event.